# Find the double-integral $\iint_{D} x\sqrt{4x^2+xy}$ on $D=\lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x=a\cos(t),y=a\sin(2t) \rbrace$ and $x \geq 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am understant that the problem is finding the limits of the integration in the region $D$, so first i draw the region $D$ which is a kind of "infinity region", so and find the principal point where this region intersects the $x$-axis and $y$-axis and $x \geq 0$ and these are $(0,a),(0,0)$ so when i try say for example while $x\in [0,a]$ i cant find the two curves equation in  which y belong.
Any help and recomendation help me much.
Sorry my English skills are low.

Comment: The set is a parametric curve, so the double integral over it will be zero.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your curve, known as member of family [Lissajous curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve), is possible to get representation $y=\pm2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$: second equation we can write as $y=2x \sin t$ and then solve $\sin t$ from 1-st equation.

If we understand your $D$ as area bounded by given curve with $x\geqslant 0$. Integral is
$$\int\limits_{0}^{a}\int\limits_{-2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}x\sqrt{4x^2+xy}\,dxdy$$

Comment: Thanks for you answer,but how do you get the expression of $y$,im try to eliminate the parametrer $t$ but i can´t, using the form $x^2+y^2$ and $x^2-y^2$ and $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{4a^2}$

Comment: @Brien Navarro. Corrected and added steps for getting representation for $y$. Write down questions, please, if/when you'll have them.

Comment: Constructive critique is welcome, especially for correct answer.

Comment: well, thanks for help me, so now i understand how do you obtain $y$.

Comment: @Brien Navarro. You are welcome. Ask more if/when you'll need it. Meanwhile, somebody down vote my answer - I asked about critique, but silence is answer.

Comment: So now I'm trying to do these integral, but I can't do it, just now I try let $u=4x^2 +xy$ and $du=xdy$ and then $\int_{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2 }{a^2 }} }^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2} {a^2 } }} u^{1/2} du=\frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{4x^2 +xy)^3} $, but when I evaluate the integral I get a terrible expression to integrate on x. So too I'm try divide the integral in two integrals, but it finish in the same Problem, can you give me one recommendation, to evaluate it, or else show me how do it.